# What does ps actually return? (Different value depending on how it is called)

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I have a script containing this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
if [ -O "myprog.pid" ]; then
    PID=`/bin/cat myprog.pid`
    if /bin/ps -p ${PID}; then
      echo "Already running" >> myprog.log
      exit 0
    else
      echo "Old pidfile found" >> myprog.log
    fi
else
    echo "No pidfile found" >> myprog.log
fi
echo $$ > myprog.pid
```

This file is called by a watchdog script, `callmyprog`, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
myprog &
```

It seems to be a problem with `if /bin/ps -p ${PID}`. The problem manifests itself in this way. If I manually call `myprog` when it is running I get the message "Already running" as it should. Same thing happens when I manually run the script `callmyprog`. But when the watchdog runs it, I instead get "Old pidfile found".

I have checked the output from `ps` and in all cases it finds the process. When I'm calling `myprog` manually - either directly or through `callmyprog`, I get the return code 0, but when the watchdog calls it I get the return code 1. I have added debug printouts to the above snippets to print basically everything, but I really cannot see what the problem is. In all cases it looks something like this in the log when the `ps` command is run from the script:

```
$ ps -p 1
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        01:06:36 systemd
```

The only difference is that the return value is different. I checked the exit code with code like this:

```
/bin/ps -p ${PID}
echo $? >> myprog.log
```

What could possibly be the cause here? Why does the return code vary depending on how I call the script? I tried to download the source code for `ps` but it was to complicated for me to understand.

I was able to "solve" the problem with an ugly hack. I piped `ps -p $PID | wc -l` and checked that the number of lines were at least 2, but that feels like an ugly hack and I really want to understand what the problem is here.

Answer to comment below:

The original script contains absolute paths so it's not a directory problem. There is no alias for `ps`. `which ps` yields `/bin/ps`. The scripts are run as root, so I cannot see how it can be a permission problem.

Comment: Your question is well written. I feel the title could be more appropriate though. How about "Return code varies depending on how I call the script (calls ps process)"

Comment: @Ely Maybe. I'm not sure. I mean, the answer to the title WILL (probably) be the answer to the question.

Comment: The code does not run; it is missing an [`elif` or a `fi`](https://pastebin.com/cezT2DYG). Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc. And maybe [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In addition, there is a mix between `myprog.pid`, where the pid is written and `$myprog.pid` (note the **`$`**) where if if read from.

Comment: @jww Fixed. Sorry about that. For certain reasons I anonymized it a bit and was clumsy in the process. However, I have really tried to create a [mre] in the debugging process, but with no luck.

Comment: There is nothing that removes `myprog.pid` so it stays existing after the process exists. Should it be removed from somewhere? Btw. for good scripting, you could handle `cat` return value, rather then `test -O`, ex. `if PID=$(cat myprog.pid 2>/dev/null); then ok; else not_ok; fi` | If it get's removed, there is something you are not showing, because, well, it should work. Anyway relaying on `ps` return value is not the best. Just `if [ -e /proc/$PID ]`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, it gets removed in another part of the script and sometimes manually. But that is not the problem.

Comment: A possible reason could be that different `ps` exist on your machine, one at `/bin/ps` and one as a shell alias. Another reason could be that the current directory of the process is not what you would expect. A last reason could be a permission problem...

Comment: @SergeBallesta The original script contains absolute paths so it's not a directory problem. There is no alias for `ps`. `which ps` yields `/bin/ps`.  The scripts are run as root, so I cannot see how it can be a permission problem.

Comment: Despite the unfortunate (but understandable) use of the word `return` in functions to provide the exit status of a function, UNIX commands don't **return** anything, they produce output and they exit with a status. For example given a shell script written as `echo 'hi'; exit 3` it is outputting `hi` and exiting with status `3` - which of those you consider the "return" from the script is up for grabs. So when you ask `What does ps actually return?` are you asking `What does ps actually output?` or `What does ps actually exit with a status of?` or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton I'm asking for how the exit status is determined.

Comment: Don't redirect multiple times.  `if ...; then ...; else ; ...; fi >> myprog.log` . Just redirect the whole stanza.

Comment: If you add a `cat myprog.pid; ps -f` at the start of the script - do you see the process you expect? Seems unlikely but maybe the UID is different between the first time you run it and the next so `ps -p` for user 2 isn't seeing the process started by user 1?

Comment: @EdMorton I'll try that in about an hour and come back with the result.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, I'll fix that. Not a solution to the problem though.

Comment: I can't see documentation of exit status anywhere in `ps` documentation, neither in BSD `ps` nor in procps-ng `ps`, maybe you simply can't rely on it?

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, it shows up. All are run by root no matter how it starts. The only noticable difference is that it seems like that those started by the watchdog seems to have ppid 1 instead of some random high number.

Comment: Try adding this at the start of your script: `ps | awk 'NR==FNR{pid=$1; printf "pid=\"%s\"n", pid; next} $1==pid{f=1} END{exit !f}' myprog.pid -; printf '$?="%s"\n' "$?"`. That will print exactly the pid seen in your myprog.pid file and do a simple test to see if it exists in the ps output and print the exit status. Please let us know what that outputs.

Comment: @EdMorton Unfortunately, I will not be able to continue debugging as I no longer have access to that code.